# Using skipTests=false in Eclipse with Maven Surefire plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, surefire

I use Maven with the surefire plugin in Eclipse to skip tests whenever I call Maven, but I also want to be able to call the test goal specifically.

I used the description from [this website](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) to set up my project and I set it up exactly as described in the "Skipping by default" part. It works well for normal Maven calls, the tests are being skipped sure enough. The setup in Bamboo also works, setting the parameter `skipTests=false` for calling the test goal has the desired effect, the tests are being executed.

However in Eclipse, this doesn't work. I defined a Maven run configuration with a test goal and set the variable `skipTests` to false. But the tests are still skipped. I then activated debug output and saw that `skipTests=false` was indeed a property, but the configuration for the Maven surefire plugin still listed that `skipTests` was true in the debug output:

```
(...)
[DEBUG]    (s) skipTests = true
(...)
```

Am I missing something or is this a problem with my versions? I use Eclipse Juno with integrated Maven 3.0.4 and the surefire plugin in version 2.14.

Comment: is it not false by default? Maybe you have the skipTests property in the POM?

Comment: Yes, I have set the property as well in the POM. That's what was being written on the website. According to the information from that website that's the way to go and it should work. And, to emphazise this, it does work with Bamboo. The question is, why does this setup, as it was proposed on the official website, not work in Eclipse?

Comment: To clarify this, I have set the property in the POM to true. I have set the Maven command in Bamboo so that it sets the property to false, overwriting the property from the POM. And in Eclipse I have configured the Run Configuration so that it also should set the property to false, also overwriting the property from the POM. But here the property from the POM seems to take precedence.